QFX10002-36Q GRE tunnel question
I have a pair of qfx10002-36q and according to their datasheet they support 2000 gre tunnels, i want to establish 5-10x GRE tunnel and each tunnel pass around ~1.5-2Gbps traffic, i want to know like other devices gre tunnels on QFX10002-36Q will handle on CPU or it will handle on asic and there is no impact on CPU ?

Tunnel interfaces (GRE included) are terminated on the PFE (ASIC). There will be no adverse impact on RE or FPC CPU.
